# Why are Arabidopsis plant seeds being sent to the moon and not other seeds?

Tags: plant-physiology, life

The latest Chang'e-4 rover [brings an entire ecosystem with it, including *Arabidopsis* plant seeds and silkworms](https://www.inverse.com/article/52175-china-chang-e-4-far-side-moon-landing-worms).

My question is: why *Arabidopsis*? Is this question conclusive without having to ask Chinese sources, such as just by having an educated guess as regards to the plant's own qualities?

Comment: Welcome to SE biology, please feel free to check our help center and take info tour to find out how  does it goes on this forum. I am afraid that this question is not suitable for this forum. Nevertheless, i think that the Chinese sent the plant there just because it is plant which is biggest model organism in plant physiology . We technicly know almost everything about this plant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without speculating further about specific decision making processes, [*Arabidopsis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabidopsis_thaliana) is *the* standard model organism in plant biology, similar to the mouse for mammals, the fruit fly for insects, *C. elegans* for nematodes, etc.

It's the first plant to have its genome sequenced, it's commonly used in undergraduate laboratory experiments in part because it grows very fast, etc.

If you were going to choose a plant arbitrarily for a research project, it might as well be *Arabidopsis*, I'd say it would be the default against which other options would be considered.